# In simple terms, How is it that 'information' is a fundamental part of reality?

Tags: information

I just learnt that information is a fundamental part of reality, as important as energy and matter.

It seems to me that information is something human's can possess (it enables us to make a better guess than random) rather than an important part of reality?

What makes information so fundamental?

Please explain as simply as possible.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354306/2451

Comment: Related question: [What is information?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/what-is-information)

Comment: -1. No research effort. Have you tried googling your question?

Comment: Yes, I've tried very hard to research this on my own. That's why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

The information in question is not the information we possess, which is very much constrained by the experimental accuracy we have. 
But rather the information in the system. The very physical variables you gave, such as mass and energy also constitute the information of the system. It is more fundamental than mass or energy or anything else for that matter because it is what allows us to Physics. The very fact that something depends on something which has happened before means that the information from the previous event had somehow traveled to the current one,be it velocity, position, mass or energy or whatever.