# Books/papers defining what information is

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, information

I'm doing research to interpret quantum physics in terms of the concept "matter is information". I'm trying to understand what is information.

I like the explanation in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2689 (including what is commented by Noldorin and Anixx). Could someone suggest me the book/papers which expand that? I seek both the mathematics and the intuition behind.

I have skimmed a couple of quantum information books. They seem to be useless overkill for the moment.

Comment: Trying to interpret which quantum physics? Nonrelativistic quantum mechanics? Relativistic quantum field theory? String theory?

Comment: I think that L.Brillouin *Science and Information Theory - 1956* remains a good classic introduction to the subject.

Comment: @G.Smith Both nonrelativistic quantum mechanics and relativistic quantum field theory, I think. It's at a fundamental level. Not esoteric string theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth noting that the term information is used in several different ways: [there is no single true definition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/information/).

Obviously Information Theory books talks about one version, stemming from Shannon Information. It can be combined with statistical mechanics and statistical inference ([Jaynes1](https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf), [Jaynes2](https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.2.pdf)).

[How the entropy in information theory is related to the entropy in thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_in_thermodynamics_and_information_theory) is a rich and big topic.

Whether information is physical is another big topic; see [Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=3327) for a good argument and references.

You are likely looking more for John Wheeler's ["It from bit" concept of physics](https://philpapers.org/archive/WHEIPQ.pdf). There is [digital physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics), but it contains a lot of disparate approaches, from Wheeler's fairly philosophical perspective to assuming the universe is a computer or is run on one.