# About information transmission speed

Tags: speed-of-light, causality, faster-than-light, information

Einstein says information cannot be transmitted faster than light.
Say I set an alarm that ring at 9:00 am. I go to school, and wait until 9:00 am. Then I tell my friends that my alarm rang. If the distance of the alarm clock and school is sufficently large, I think I can say the information that alarm rang is transmitted faster than the light. Why is this wrong? + If information means number of yes/no questions you need to get answered to fully specify the system, how do that 'move'?

Comment: It is wrong because no information is actually _transmitted._ Having a thought about your clock is not the same as receiving information from your clock.

Comment: What is information transmission?

Comment: It's literally in the title and body of your question. It means the movement/transfer of information from one point to another. Are you asking what _information_ is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is information?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2685/)

Comment: If information is 'number of yes/no questions you need to get answered to fully specify the system', how does that 'move'?

Comment: The thing is, you don't in fact *know* the alarm went off. Maybe someone else turned it off, or maybe it malfunctioned. All you've  transmitted to your friends is your own personal guess as to the state of the distant alarm.

Comment: Say I made sure that the alarm doesn't go off. If the universe is deterministic, it is possible to control future state by setting the proper present state